# Full Calander with Line breaks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Any help would be amazing I'm been stuck for ages trying to get this to work

I've got a textarea named notes this data is pulled via full calendar event.

```
<textarea   style="white-space: pre-wrap; text-indent: 50px;" name="notes" id="notes" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

The issue is that when I add a new line in the textarea using enter it's then causes the full calendar to break!

I'm trying to work out how I can keep new lines in a text area so it can be saved saved in the DB without any line spaces! I've tried `nl2br()`  it's still creating new lines!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

                      
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

   
    events : [
                @foreach($bookings as $booking)
                {
                    bookingId : '{{ $booking->id }}',
                    title : '{{ $booking->booking_contact }}',
                    start : '{{ $booking->booking_start }}',
                    end: '{{ $booking->booking_end }}',
                    content : '{{ $booking->notes }}',

                },
                @endforeach
    ],
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view, event) {
        $('#bookingId').val(calEvent.bookingId);
        $('#booking_start').val(moment(calEvent.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#booking_end').val(moment(calEvent.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#title').val(calEvent.title);
        $('#notes').val(calEvent.content);
        $('#editModal').modal();
    }
});
    });
</script>
```

The error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at 5:223:31)

Sources in chrome this is the db row notes

```
content : 'Arriving at 19.20pm
Departing at 20.05pm
1075 euros cash on arrival....',

                },
```

Comment: This looks like corrupt JSON. Trailing comma is invalid. Also `content` needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @json directive

```
   ... 

   events: @json($bookings->map(function ($booking) {
        return [
            'bookingId' => $booking->id,
            'title' => $booking->booking_contact,
            'start' => $booking->booking_start,
            'end' => $booking->booking_end,
            'content' => $booking->notes,
        ];
    }))
```